# Insert distinct data into Combobox List

Tags: vb.net

I just want to ask if how to insert my distinct data to my combobox?

i.e.

```
dim query as string
query = "SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM tblEmployees" 

combobox1.text = ????
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
dim query as string
query = "SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM tblEmployees" 

Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = query
Me.ComboBox1.Refresh
```

Comment: hi johnny, just wondering why i don't have .rowsource in my combobox?. I mean when i type combobox1. it doesn't have rowsource on the selection, do i need to import something?.

Comment: Did you try to run the code?  Intellisense isn't always right.

Comment: From this user's [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964307/how-do-i-insert-distinct-values-into-my-combobox?lq=1) it seems he's running VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data from your Access database into a VB.NET program, you can use instances of the [OleDbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx), [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and [OleDbDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

You will need to compose a [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/). That link also provides details about constructing connection strings for other versions of Access.

Your SQL statement should look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FieldName
FROM TableName
```

Iterate through the `OleDbDataReader` using the [Do..Loop statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx).

Items are added to a WinForms combobox [using the `Combobox`'s `Items.Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7). You can use this method within the `Do..Loop` to add the items.

Another option you might consider, especially if you want to process the data using .NET code before putting it into the combo box (processing that can be done with SQL is usually more performant in SQL), is to put each item into some collection and then you can use `Items.AddRange` method to add multiple items at once.