# How do i insert distinct values into my combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I just want to ask if how could i insert distinct values created by my query into a combobox?. I have an employee database that consist of 100 records and 5 different departments.

Comment: Is this a combobox in an Access Forms project?

Comment: combobox in visual basic sir.

Comment: @JgzTradamus VBA in Access, VB6, or VB.NET? They're all very different.

Answer (score 0):

For the RowSource of your combo box, just add the word "DISTINCT" to your SQL string.